# Problem while trying to open legion app

Tags: python, pip

sudo legion

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/legion/legion.py", line 19, in 
from app.ProjectManager import ProjectManager
File "/usr/share/legion/app/ProjectManager.py", line 23, in 
from app.Project import Project, ProjectProperties
File "/usr/share/legion/app/Project.py", line 20, in 
from app.auxiliary import Wordlist
File "/usr/share/legion/app/auxiliary.py", line 21, in 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'**

already tried to do
pip install python-qt5
got this error

**ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-9tH4HC**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can not comment:
(on Linux mint) have you tried: `pip3 install --upgrade pip`
and `pip3 install pyqt5==x.xx.x` where x is the version number?

from link [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711301/install-pyqt5-5-14-1-on-linux)

ciao

Comment: oh i do not know if this works on your kali system